# How Can I full screen one panel of several panels, and toFront any panel of several panels

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I designed a split pane embedded with several panels like this:

[image]

My question is: if I want to fullscreen and toFront one of the panel, for example, the upper one, how can I do this?

I have tried something:
  1) set the stage to fullscreen
  2) use another panel for example newPane embedded with the upper panel
  3) then scene = new Scene(newPanel), but just horizontally full screen. Like this:
  [image]

Can you see that, the lower part is empty, is there anyone knowing how can I implement such a function -- fullscreen and toFront specified panel?

Thank you so much for any advices!

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the `graph`'s height and width with that of the scene's.

```
graph.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
graph.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I appreciated.
Actually the height of newPanel does change to the ideal size. But the graph is the same as the second graph above. I tried stage.setFullScreen(false) and stage.setFullScreen(true). It doesn't change. Do you have some advice about this? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Try using `graph` instead of `newPanel`. If it doesn't work, please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem and share it.